# UIViewControllerTransistion like in Apple's Podcast App

Tags: animation, ios7, uicollectionview, podcast

i have a question on iOS7 and the Custom UiViewControllerTransistion. I want to make a custom transistion between a fullscreen UiCollectionView and a modal View (iPad) with the details of the selected item on the collectionView. The animation should be like that when you tapped on a item in the collection the item will scale/zoom to the final Position of the Modal View with the details, and when you tapped then outside the modal view, the modal will be dismiss automatically. The dismiss animtion should be a kind of reverse animation. It should seems to be that the modal view "falling back" to the item in the UICollectionView. The transistion is the like in the Apple Podcasts App on the iPad, when you select a Podcasts and it will show you the details of Podcats in a kind of Modal View. I hope you can understand what i mean:)

So i have no idea if its only a custom transistion or if i need a custom uicollectionviewlayout for it. It would be nice if you can explain what i have to do for it.

xxAvarlonxx

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the frame of the tapped collectionViewItem. This is done like follows

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [collectionView layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGRect cellRect = [attributes frame];
}
```

Then you initiate your viewcontroller, set its frame to the frame of the cell and then use `-animateWithDuration:completion:` to make the animation.

I actually did that even in iOS6.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Yes thats close to my best idea at the moment. Give the AnimationController the frame of the selected Item and then making a UIview Snapshot of the toView, inital give him the frame of the selectedItem and the start a animation to the real toViewFinalFrame. Now i need to know how to get the frame of the selected item. Who can know this? The CollectionView? The Section in the Collection View? Have anyone an idea?

Comment: Okay it seems to be easy. You only need the selected cell and can take the frame from it "cell.frame". Wow when it works, i will be really surprised how easy it is:)

Comment: No. cell.frame will NOT give you the correct position on screen! PLEASE use layoutAttributes :-)

Comment: Yeah, sounds gread, keep me up to date! If my answer did help you please consider accepting ;-)